# Visual Studio 2010 Web Developer Express Tools.Attach to Process is not exists

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-web-developer

I have loaded Web Site from HDD. Now trying attach it to process WebDev.WebServer.EXE. But in  **Visual Studio 2010 Web Developer Express** edition of VS not exist tool **Attach To Process**. Is it normal? if yes, how can add this tool or solve my needs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Attach To Process is not available in the Expressor the Web Developer Editions**. You will need to purchase a full version. See **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6wf8e4z.aspx)**.

Comment: can I add this functionality? or attach from command prompt? or if it is possible from IIS? Because, I'm not going to purchase a full version.

Comment: @loviji - Nope, this is no different from any other software, there are more features in the paid version...many more features.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to use Attach To Process on IIS process, when using Visual Studio Express for Web as your dev IDE:

- Open your web site project in Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web,
  and browse your dev website in a browser - You can do it by Ctrl+F5 in VS (start without debugging) - this will run w3wp.exe (ISS Application Pool Process - this process will run when your project Web Location is HTTP)
- Open Visual Studio express 2012 for **windows desktop**. yes. for "windows desktop" - here will come the trick (-:
- In the VS for desktop - press Ctrl+O (Open File) - and browse to file in website that you want to debug -  [root]/Default.aspx.cs for example.
  Now in the Default.aspx.cs code, set a Breakpoint - for example in
  Page_Load event code
- In the VS for desktop - go to Debug menu and select Attach To Process...
  In the Attach To Process dialog - in the Available Process list select your IIS process: w3wp.exe
  Now press Attach button
- Go to your browser and run the /Default.aspx page

Result:
The website run in IIS process, will stop in the breakpoint in the VS for desktop, and you can debug it.

Notes:

- This will work only if your website project Web Location is HTTP (this configured when creating the website project in the VS. [Google for instructions](http://www.google.com/search?q=Creating%20a%20Local%20IIS%20Web%20Site%20in%20Visual%20Studio))
- I did it on 2012 version, and it may work on other versions as well.